# Showing that UPDOWNUP is not a context-free language

Tags: context-free-grammar

Define the formal language UPDOWNUP as $L = \{ s(reverse(s))s,s \in (a+b)^* \}
= \{aaa,bbb,aaaaaa,abbaab, baabba, bbbbbb, ... \}$

I want to show using the pumping-lemma for context free languages that this language is not context free.

**My thoughts:**
By the pumping lemma if this was a context free language, then for any word which has length greater than $2^p$, where $p$ is the number of live productions of the grammar, then it must be of the form $w=uvxyz$ where $v,y$ cannot both be empty, and $x$ is not empty, and for any $n \in \Bbb N$

$ uv^nxy^nz$ must be in the language.

I have had the idea to try using either $a^na^na^n$ where $n > 2^p$ or $a^nb^nb^na^na^nb^n$ to find a contradiction.

In the former, it seems that If I decompose $a^{3n}$ then I notice that the new word formed by taking powers of $v,y$ must result with a word where the number of "a's" is divisible by 3 since $length((s)reverse(s)(s))=3length(s))$, but this is do-able if both $v,y$ are powers of $a$ that are divisible by 3, so I am not sure how to proceed.

If anything is unclear I will edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: @saulspatz yup sorry, that's a typo.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've looked at this stuff, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) says $|vxy|\le p,$ which I guess would be $2^p$  in your formulation, and you don't seem to have stated this.  Should it not apply?  Also, I see that you say $x$ is not empty, which the wiki doesn't.

Comment: @saulspatz my description of the pumping lemma is accurate to my notes, which may differ from Wikipedia. Although I believe these definitions are equivalent as you have described.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can do this with the description in Wikipedia.  I'll just outline my idea, and you can see if you can apply it with your definition.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) we must have $|vxy|\le n$ where $n$ is the pumping length.  Consider the string $a^nb^nb^na^na^nb^n=a^nb^{2n}a^{2n}b^n$  The condition $|vxy|\le n$ make it clear that $v$ or $y$ (or both) can only contain one distinct symbol.  Also, since every string in the language contains an equal number of $a\text{'s}$ and $b\text{'s},$ the string $vy$ must contain an equal number of $a\text{'s}$ and $b\text{'s}$ for the pumping to work.

Now you have to work though the cases.  If $vxy$ overlaps the initial $a^nb^n,$ then after you pump, the first string of $a\text{'s}$ will be loner than the second string of $a\text{'s},$ and the resulting string won't be in the language.  (This probably takes a bit of argument, but it seems clear.)  The other cases should be similar.

I can't quite see how to proceed if we don't know that there's a bound on the length of $vxy,$ though.  I notice that the formulation of the pumping lemma for context-free languages is given on Wikipedia is the same as Theorem 7.18 in the third edition of Hopcraft, Motwani, and Ullman.